# How can i populate and optimize DropDownList from WebService using Select2.js

Tags: asp.net, jquery-select2

I'm working on *customer selection* module that will `autocomplete` while typing. It seems that `Select2.js` would do the job, I already managed to populate my `dropdownlist` but on the back-end (`.cs` file) with a simple data binding.

The problem is, I am only working with a sample data of 15 customers so the performance is just fine, i am expecting an actual data of almost 2000 customers so just by binding would messed up the performance.

here is my code for the binding event and implementation of `select2.js`

*`.aspx` file:*

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCustomers" CssClass="form-control" async="">
   <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

*`.cs` file:*

```
protected void BindDropDownCustomers()
{
    DataTable dt = SharedClass.getAPI("CustomerProfile_All"); //Returns Data from Webservice
    DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn();

    //just formating the display
    newColumn.ColumnName = "FullName";
    newColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    newColumn.Expression = "Cust_Last_Name+', '+Cust_First_Name";
    dt.Columns.Add(newColumn);
    ddlCustomers.DataTextField = "FullName";
    ddlCustomers.DataValueField = "SmartCardID";
    ddlCustomers.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    ddlCustomers.DataBind();
    ddlCustomers.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Customer", ""));
}
```

*`select2.js` script:*

```
$('#<%= ddlCustomers.ClientID %>').select2({
   placeholder: "Select customer",
   minimumResultsForSearch: 2,
   minimumInputLength: 3,
   allowClear: true
});
```

I want something like, after the user enters a minimum of 3 characters, a query will be executed and get all related data that will populate the `dropdownlist` and limit or optimize the display at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, In my opinion, running a loop 2,000 times on a client machine using `javascript` *(it would be better to check if the chars that were typed by user were more than 3 here)* is fine instead of making a call to the server and opening `SQL Connection` to query something whenever user types something. Think of it as when the network will be slow the lag would be more and what if tens of thousands users make the same call to the server and server is just searching through the records? Well that was just an opinion. Of course, you can decide what is suitable for you.

If you still want to do it, you can either look out for some paid controls or see if there is one in ajax toolkit.
Moreover, if you want to do it in a custom way then you can use `jquery-ui autocomplete` to achieve the task.

I am not going to give the source code to do that but here is the rough idea that you might want to do:

1. Show a basic few records on load
2. Hook up `jQuery-UI autocomplete` to the text box that is searching and returning the results from the db
3. Add Custom HTML when you get the respond as it is in your HTML page and Hook up `jquery/javascript` events to select the relevant values.

Hope this gives a rough idea.

Comment: actually **select2.js** has _minimumInputLength_ which already checks the chars inputted on client. But i will also try to work on _JQuery-ui autocomplete_, i'm just thinking if in that case, how can i get hidden value of a selected result. because in select2, it's a select element, and has value. Textbox on the otherhand just autocomplete it.

Comment: Well, what I suggested was, you can hook up `autocomplete` to the input control inside of your select2.js dropdown this way a user can have a dropdown like experience and you can just query data behind the scene. And of course, if you want to use a textbox, you can use it but whenever the item gets selected you can save the value inside of a hidden field that only tracks the selected value from the dropdown and clears when user starts typing something or changes content of the text box.

Comment: Moreover, if you inspect the displayed select2.js drop down list, you will see that it is not using a select item, it translates your select item to an un-ordered list.